# Save file name to database and upload file to server

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, file-upload

I have a code that I want to modify, got it somewhere online. It does exactly what I want i.e upload image, preview, crop and save. However, when it comes to save, it saves the image it's self to the database instead of saving the filename to the database and file to the server.

Here is the code

```
if(isset($_POST["image"]))
{
 include('database_connection.php');
 $data = $_POST["image"];
 $image_array_1 = explode(";", $data);
 $image_array_2 = explode(",", $image_array_1[1]);
 $data = base64_decode($image_array_2[1]);
 $imageName = time() . '.png';
 file_put_contents($imageName, $data);
 $image_file = addslashes(file_get_contents($imageName));
 $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_images(images) VALUES ('".$image_file."')";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 if($statement->execute())
 {
  echo 'Image save into database';
  unlink($imageName);
 }
}
```

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){

 $image_crop = $('#image_demo').croppie({
    enableExif: true,
    viewport: {
      width:200,
      height:200,
      type:'square' //circle
    },
    boundary:{
      width:300,
      height:300
    }    
  });

  $('#insert_image').on('change', function(){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (event) {
      $image_crop.croppie('bind', {
        url: event.target.result
      }).then(function(){
        console.log('jQuery bind complete');
      });
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    $('#insertimageModal').modal('show');
  });

  $('.crop_image').click(function(event){
    $image_crop.croppie('result', {
      type: 'canvas',
      size: 'viewport'
    }).then(function(response){
      $.ajax({
        url:'insert.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{"image":response},
        success:function(data){
          $('#insertimageModal').modal('hide');
          load_images();
          alert(data);
        }
      })
    });
  });

  load_images();

  function load_images()
  {
    $.ajax({
      url:"fetch_images.php",
      success:function(data)
      {
        $('#store_image').html(data);
      }
    })
  }

});  
</script>
```

```
<input type="file" name="insert_image" id="insert_image" accept="image/*" />
```

I would really like to save the image/file name to the database and upload the file to a folder on the server.
Any modification to help me achieve what I want is highly appreciated.

Comment: Post your HTML/form for this please, so we can see just what it is we're dealing with. Handling files requires the $_FILES superglobal and not $_POST along with the proper enctype.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner javascript id handling all the front end work, nonetheless, let me post the javascript code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are getting image is wrong. You have to use `$_FILES` to get the image data. You are using `$_POST`.

Comment: I already said that in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58147655/save-file-name-to-database-and-upload-file-to-server#comment102680136_58147655) above.

Comment: Ok, let me change that and see the results @lalit

Comment: @HackZaid ok, please check and if you find correct, please accept my answer. thank you

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner This is a basic problem. everyone will suggest that solution. it does not mean that you will make others answers unuseful. So, please make my answer useful.